Trying to use a the Tutorial's Custom Writer for Pandoc, what CLI options need to use?
I am following the tutorial of the docs, example-modified-markdown-writer
I want to try it against the following file
input01.html


<body>
<h1>My Document</h1>

<code>
This code will be recognised
</code>

</body>

custom-write01A.lua


function Writer (doc, opts)
  local filter = {
    CodeBlock = function (cb)
      -- only modify if code block has no attributes
      if cb.attr == pandoc.Attr() then
        local delimited = '```\n' .. cb.text .. '\n```'
        return pandoc.RawBlock('markdown', delimited)
      end
    end
  }
  return pandoc.write(doc:walk(filter), 'gfm', opts)
end

Template = pandoc.template.default 'gfm'

Now I can do the default markdown processing by
pandoc -f html -t markdown input01.html

Or I could be picking the custom writer
pandoc -f html input01.html -L custom-writer01.lua

Which is giving me
<h1 id="my-document">My Document</h1>
<p><code> This code will be recognised </code></p>

I was expecting the output in the gfm
I expected the output to be as specified per code (In a fenced code block)

# My Document

```
This code will be recognised
```

Instead we get the in-line codeblock as the same as in -t markdown
# My Document

` This code will be recognised `


what's the question? I don't understand the sentence "I was expecting the output in the gfm"

you mean you want the output format to be gfm? then run pandoc -t gfm -f html input01.html -L custom-writer01.lua

Sorry I didnt put it clear cause I didnt know how to escape markdown on markdown.
It has been written in the post again , it was appended the expeted output.

If the input is <pre><code>foo</code></pre>, then you can just use pandoc -f html -t gfm, no filter necessary. Play around with the -t native option or have a look at the manual to see the difference between "code block" and "inline code".

Thank you.
I understand now better. Now the issue is. I am trying to use this custom writer using the -t parameter. pandoc -f html -t custom-writer01.lua input01.html and it says custom-writer01.lua does not contain a custom writer
